# coldfusion variables into powershell

Tags: powershell, coldfusion, cfexecute

I have a simple powershell script that creates a txt file thus:-

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted -force

$MyVar = 'My Content'

$MyVar | out-file -FilePath "C:\_Testing\test.txt"
```

This is called from a ColdFusion script here:-

```
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    arguments="C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\testsite\wwwroot\_Testing\powershellTest.ps1"/>
```

And that works - creates the txt file and puts the content in but what I want to do though is pass a variable through the cfexecute into the $MyVar so that the content is dynamic.

any help much appreciated

Paul

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but can you put a unique string in your `.ps1` file? Something like `$MyVar = 'CFVARIABLEGOESHERE'`? Then, before you use `cfexecute` you could use `CFFILE` to open your `.ps1` file, find and replace 'CFVARIABLEGOESHERE' with anything you'd like. Once you've done your replace, you could then use cfexecute to call the newly saved file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a script that has parameters.  Parameter definitions are put at the top of your script, and look like this:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    # Variable to test that parameter is getting set from ColdFusion
    $MyVar
)

$MyVar | Set-Content "C:\_Testing\test.txt"
```

First come attributes, which are meta data about the parameter.  In the example, we are stating the parameters is mandatory and PowerShell will give an error if a value isn't provided.

Next comes the variable's type.  You can use any .NET type, e.g. `[int]`, `[DateTime]`, `[Hashtable]`, etc.

After the type, is the variable's documentation, useful when somebody runs `Get-Help powershellTest.ps1`.

Finally, we declare the variable, `$MyVar`.

You can get more information about parameters, parameter attributes, validation, etc. on the [about_functions_advanced_parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) help topic.

Now, the tricky part is that your call to PowerShell is actually going through `cmd.exe` *first*, so depending on the value of your script's parameter, you may need to do some funky magic to get things quoted correctly.

Also, use `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`.  `Out-File` is intended for saving binary objects and data and will encode text files in UCS-2.  `Set-Content` will encode the files in ANSI/UTF-8.

Comment: Brilliant - that is exactly the answer - works perfectly... For others the cf code looks like this:- <cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
        arguments="C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\_Testing\powershellTest2.ps1 -MyVar 'Test Content'"/>

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make it in to a function that allows parameters.  Then you can call the function with the params as necessary.

Example:

```
function CreateText
{
  param ( [string]$MyVar
  )

 $MyVar | out-file -FilePath "C:\_Testing\test.txt"

}

CreateText -MyVar "Content Here"
```

And you can call it this way:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
arguments="C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\testsite\wwwroot\_Testing\powershellTest.ps1 -MyVar "conent" "/>
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I think that's nearly there but not quite. 

I've change the powershell script so it looks like this:-

    function CreateText
    {
      param ( [string]$MyVar)

     $MyVar | out-file -FilePath     "C:\_Testing\test1.txt"
    }
    CreateText -MyVar $MyVar 

and my cf script to:-

    <cfexecute name="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
        arguments="C:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\ignite.flinthosts.co.uk\wwwroot\_Testing\powershellTest1.ps1 -MyVar 'content' "/>

no content is passed through :(