# jquery and MS Exchange - stopped working with Coldfusion/WebDAV

Tags: jquery, exchange-server

I've been using the CFEXCHANGE tags to insert calendar events in on hosted Exchange server.  Apparently Intermedia upgraded to version 2010 and removed Webdav which kills the CF tags.  Is there a jQuery plugin, etc., that will handle the Exchange interface?  I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: As far as I am aware, Intermedia supports EWS and WebDAV for their Exchange service. Also they  move customers from one Exchange platform to another upon request. They don't do in place upgrades. Something else may have changed within their systems.

Found this article they have in their KB too: http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=2249


What error are you getting?

Comment: They actually told me that they didn't support WebDav anymore.  I went off on a tangent looking for a solution.  I talked to them again (at least 2 more times) and they told me that the tech that told me that was wrong but they didn't have a way help me figure out the problem.  I still can't connect to the exchange server.

Comment: What version of Exchange are they hosting for you?

Comment: I'm not sure of the version of Exchange but my account is using Outlook 2007.

Comment: Well Outlook 2007 could connect to either Exchange 2007 or 2010. What errors did you encounter when you were testing `CFEXCHANGE` before. I don't see why it wouldn't work, I see from their KBs they support EWS on both Exchange 2007 and 2010, and EWS uses WebDAV. Using the CF Tags is the only way I know to get CF to interact with Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the API against Exchange 2010 needs to be done over PowerShell these days, so you're probably going to have to go server-side instead of jQuery. [Here's a pretty good tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/23/learn-how-to-use-powershell-to-run-exchange-server-commands-remotely.aspx) on how to get started.

I've used remote Powershell for Exchange management before, even with our on-premises infrastructure, and it's not all that bad.

There's also an [managed API library for Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) if you're interested, but it's just for on-premises Exchange.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So, I would have to go from my Coldfusion page to Powershell to the Exchange server?

Comment: I'm no CF developer, but essentially, yes. You'd have to shell it out to a Powershell window and invoke the commands from there. That's really the main way to make calls to hosted Exchange environments these days. In .NET, you can invoke PowerShell (even remotely) from managed code, but I've never tried it in ColdFusion. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528100/coldfusion-variables-into-powershell](Looks like people have done so before, though).